# chrome.alarms api doesn't work properly with angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, angularjs

I'm working on a chrome extension using angluarJS, now I have a issue that totally burned me brain.
I want to grab data ,parse that data and store the parsed data in localStorage at background page, and fetch that data at browser action and display that in popup html. Now I want to grab
, parse and store data repeatedly, as mentioned http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html, I use chrome.alarms api to do that, but it doesn't work properly.

Here's my code in background controller:

```
app.controller('bgCtrl', function AlfredCtrl($scope, courseService) {
  var setLocal = function(){
      console.log("fired inside setLocal(), but out of getCourses()");
      courseService.getCourses().then(function (events){
          console.log("fired inside of getCourses()");
          localStorage.setItem("deadlines", JSON.stringify(events.deadlines));
      })
  };

  var delay = 1 ;
  chrome.alarms.create("scheduleRequest", {periodInMinutes: delay});

  chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm){
      if(alarm.name == "scheduleRequest"){
          console.log("fired out of setLocal()");
          setLocal();
      }
  });
});
```

The function getCourses() is returned from services in bg. When it's called, it will return the parsed data.

When I inspect in chrome dev tool, it displays repeatedly:

```
fired out of setLocal().                           bgCtrl.js:32
fired inside setLocal(), but out of getCourses().  bgCtrl.js:7
```

That is to say the function courseService.getCourses() were not been callec at all.That's the problem I have.

Please help me!!

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: I am very interested in it.

Answer (score -1):

You may add the "alarms" permission in the manifest.json

This way your app will have access the Chrome apis's alarm capabilities

"permissions": [
  "alarms",
  ...
  ...
],

Comment: It would definitely present different errors if that was the cause.